# Pagination query

Tags: pagination

Pagination query/issue.

The client/design for a site am building requires the first page to show fewer entries than subsequent pages so been guessing have to write some own/custom pagination jiggery pokery.

If I dynamically apply the values I want to pass into my `{% paginate %}` tag it's not working as expected. Any thoughts why?

To provide an example, I have a section with 20 entries in it. The first page should return 5 entries but subsequent pages should show 12.

So on page one I set a limit of `5` and an offset of `0`, eg `{% paginate list.offset(p).limit(l) as info, entries %}` - where `list` is my entries, `p` is 0 and `l` is 5 - and this works as expected.

However, for subsequent pages, eg for page 2 where `p` is 5 and `l` is 12` (offset of 5 and a limit of 12)  am only getting 3 entries on the page.

Any suggestions? Do I just need to roll my pagination using `{% craft.entries %}` instead? (edited)

think will have to bypass native pagination entirely. If I dump out the info from my pagination query I get

```
'first' => 18
'last' => 15
'total' => 15
'currentPage' => 2
'totalPages' => 2
```

Is there a simpler way of rolling this out rather than some custom work?

Comment: I may be reading this wrong but your dump indicates you have 15 entries in total and not 20? Are some disabled or in some way excluded from your query?.

Comment: Wait... Page 0 shows 5, Page 1 shows 12, Page 2 shows 3. So that's 5+12+3 = 20.